# How to differentiate whether a microcontroller pin is an output at 0V or an input?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

Is it possible to electrically differentiate without having access to the code? I'm using a MC9S12XEP100 microcontroller.

Comment: Try pulling it up and see if it resists?

Comment: Determine what it is connected to.  These days a lot of connections go to one device.

Comment: Pulling up with high resistance (standard 10k) as suggested by @winny is a really good idea. Input will go higher (not necessarily to 5V, but higher), output 0 will stay strictly at (very close to) 0

Comment: @winny it is really a good idea. But I noticed here that the pin is connected to another pin on the same microcontroller, so maybe it would no to work properly

Comment: If you have an output pin connected to an input pin it is generally impossible to tell which is which just be observing the voltage of the pins. You should have added the fact that the pin was connected to something else in your question. At this point you should probably add a schematic of the circuit in question with links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the components involved.

Comment: Do you have JTAG (or some other debugging interface) to the device? You could read the register value directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: As Winny says, try pulling that input up with a resistor, and see how "high" it gets. Any measurement device (multimeter or 'scope) simply attached to an I/O pin may pull it "low" via its internal resistance. An AC-coupled 'scope may not pull low.

An input-output pin with *nothing connected* is likely to be an output rather than input. Unterminated inputs indicate bad design, since it can float around at any voltage. Especially egregious is a floating input that sits roughly half-way between GND and Vdd (for CMOS logic)...a lot of power is wasted.

An input pin may have a pull-up or pull-down resistor attached external to the I/O pin, or an internal weak pull-up/pull-down may be enabled.
In this case, an external resistor temporarily attached (while monitoring with a 'scope) may be successful in pulling that pin high. The top-end of that resistor should be terminated at the chip's Vdd - no higher. The value of pull-up resistor might be 1000 ohms or so. In this way, you can tell how tightly tied to GND that I/O pin is held. If it hardly moves from zero volts, chances are that it is actively driven low.

Example:
A 3.6V HCMOS chip has an I/O pin to be tested. A multimeter shows 0.0 V with nothing connected.

When a 1k resistor is connected to Vdd (+3.6V), the multimeter reads 0.1 V between I/O pin and GND.

There would be 3.5 mA current flowing through that 1k resistor. Somewhere between I/O pin and GND is a resistance of about 28 ohms, since I/O pin has changed from 0 to 0.1 V. This would suggest that the I/O pin is actively pulling low, and is an **OUTPUT**.

---

Internal pullup or pulldown resistors for this chip (internal) ranges between 25k to 50k ohms. If you wish to discriminate between deciding if an I/O pin is *actively* pulled low or if it is merely *pulled-down* with a resistor, then a test resistor of 1k might be a bit strong...
Try a 33k resistor pullup to +Vdd.
If the pin pulls up to  around +1.8 V, then the pin is internally pulled down and not actively driven down, as an output pin would.